# What image size is suitable for MaskRCnn?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, object-detection, faster-rcnn

I am training a MaskRcnn on document images with size (256,256,3) and unable to get a good accuracy. if I increase the image size the code throw GPU memory gull error. Should I increase the training image? What else can I do to improve the accuracy.

```
Training set size = 1000 images
Classes = 45
GPU = Nvidia GTX 1060
Actual Image resolution = 9000 x 6600
```

Comment: I think you have to increase your training image's resolution because your actual image resolution is too big to resize(256,256,3). How about change your batch size if your GPU memory has not enough space to train?

Answer (score 0):

As your image size is small try to use SSD model instead of maskrcnn model, this will give better detection time as well.